# What are Repositories, Services, and Actions/Controllers?

Tags: php, design-patterns, slim

I started a project using Slim3 and PHP using limited knowledge of application architecture. The plan was to create the project and separate application concerns. It was all going well, but things got confusing fast as the application grew.

The whole idea for doing this was to make development easier. It does in a way, but I find it's complex at times to keep tabs on the data flow.

I need some advice on what Repositories, Services and Controllers/Actions are. And how they should work in a system. My current understanding of them is below:

**Repository**

Repositories are used between the service layer and the model layer. For example, in a `UserRepository` you would create methods that contains the code to read/write from the database. In PHP PDO would be used, or an ORM, within the repo methods. For example:

```
class UserRepository
{
    public function findByID($id) { ... }
    public function findByEmail($email) { ... }
    public function findByMobile($mobile) { ... }
    public function createEmail($email, $firstname, $lastname, $password) { ... }
    public function createMobile($mobile, $firstname, $lastname, $password) { ... }
}
```

I've put a few example methods in there. But there would likely be many more.

**Services**

The service layer encapsulates application logic. For example, the `UserService` would be responsible for creating an account, and performing the required logic in order to register the user. Services can also be third party, for example creating a service for Facebook's SDK, or ORM.

An example service:

```
class UserService
{
    public function createMobile($mobile, $firstname, $lastname, $password)     {
    /*
     * Call a validation service to validate input
     */
    ...

    /*
     * Use UserRepository's findByMobile() to check if account exists
     */
    ...

    /*
     * Use UserRepository's createMobile() to create account
     */
    ...

    /*
     * Call SMS service to send verification code
     */
    ...
    }

    public function createEmail(...) { ... }
    public function getFollowers (...) { ... }
}
```

**Actions**

I'm not sure if this is a real term. It's used in the Slim Framework documentation and seems to represent a thin controller.

An Action contains very little logic and is used to make calls to services. Rarely does the Action make direct calls to the repositories unless there's a valid reason. The Action will perform basic checks on the data returned from the services in order to send a response back to the client.

They're tied to individual routes. I'm using them like so:

```
class ActivateEmailAction extends Action {

    public function __invoke(Request $request, Response $response, $args = [])
    {
        if(!$this->ci->ActivationService->activateEmail($args['token'])){
            return $response->withJson([
                'status' => 'error',
                'data' => null,
                'message' => 'Invalid verification token'
            ]);
        };

        return $response->withJson([
            'status' => 'success',
            'data' => null,
            'message' => null
        ]);
    }
}
```

Am I using these patterns correctly? The flow I seem to have adopted is like so:

1. Everything starts at the route. For example a request is made to `/create`. The route is registered to an Action.
2. Action decides what services to call
3. Services perform the logic, make calls to other services and repositories if required
4. Service hands back data to the Action
5. Action returns a response

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: I see a close has been voted as too broad. I disagree. Designing applications using such design patterns usually only has one correct answer. For example, you wouldn't be consuming services from with a repository and that would be bad practice. I could very well be doing things that are considered bad practices due to potential gaps in knowledge, which is why I've asked.

Comment: Everything you do is fine - was that the answer you were looking for? )

Comment: @GeorgyIvanov with my knowledge being limited and much of it based on guess work or common sense I assumed that somewhere down the line I'm doing it incorrectly because I'm still facing some amount of complexity whilst managing the project.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Am I using these patterns correctly?

Yes, you are. General advice I'd give is not to give your classes in general and services in particular too many responsibilities: follow single responsibility principle, which, basically states "my class should have only one reason to change" (<s>that's M.Fowler, as far as I remember</s> that actually was [R. Martin](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByOwmqah_nuGNHEtcU5OekdDMkk/view), thanks to Gordon's correction in the comment).

Your `UserService` seems to be handling too many different tasks: it handles registration and grabs followers. And probably sends SMS. Extract registration-related logic into `UserRegistrationService` class.

Comment: Ah, very good advice on SRP. I often get stuck when deciding "Where is the best place for this to go". As a result I've got classes that are doing too much. Generally, when you follow SRP will that significantly increase the number of classes in the application?

Comment: @BugHunterUK, yes, but isn't it exactly what you will do? Break "big god" classes into "smaller focused" classes. ) As for "too many classes" - you are unlikely to encounter such problem, as long as your code is logically organized.

Answer (score -4):

If you have a limited knowledge of application architecture, I would suggest you to read this book about design patterns first: http://amzn.eu/aNVH8Ii

The second point is not to use slim framework. It is a small framework for people, who already know what they want to build and how to do it. Definitely not a framework to learn any patterns or application architecture.

I would suggest to take a look at Yii 2: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-index.html

Yii uses most design patterns and architecture solutions, which are commonly used in big applications today, and is easy to learn and understand.

Comment: Slim is an excellent framework to learn patterns, since it forces you to actually create an architecture of your application.
And Yii is a no-no for architetural best practices.

Comment: Why not? And as I said, these are suggestions. For me it is easier understand patterns by looking inside a big framework because you see how they are used in production and not on the paper. Theory without practice is not very helpful.